# Existence of functions/sequences with certain properties

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to figure out whether the following exist:

(1) A power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}z^{n}$ having radius of convergence 1 and such that for every positive integer $k$, the polynomial $\sum_{n=0}^{k}c_{n}z^{n}$ has no zeroes when $|z|<1$. [I thought of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n}$.]

(2) A holomorphic function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ having an essential singularity at 0 and such that $|f(z)|<1$ in the half-plane where $\operatorname{Re}z<0$.

(3) A sequence $(u_{n})$ of harmonic functions on the unit disk such that $-1<u_{n}(z)<1$ for every positive integer $n$ and every point $z$ in the unit disk, yet the sequence $(u_{n})$ has no subsequence that converges uniformly on compact subsets of the unit disk. [This seems to be in the spirit of Montel's theorem but I'm not sure about harmonic functions.]

(4) A holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ that has an essential singularity at each integer. [$e^{1/z}$ has an essential singularity at 0 so I was thinking whether if I construct an entire function $f$ with zeroes at the integers, then $e^{1/f(z)}$ might work.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1). $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$  works. To see $\sum_{n=0}^k z^n$ has no zeroes when $|z|<1$, note that $$(z-1)\sum_{n=0}^k z^n=z^{n+1}-1.$$

(2). Let $f(z)=e^{\frac{1}{z}}$. Note that $|f(x+iy)|=e^{\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}}$.

(3). It is impossible. Let $v_n$ be the harmonic conjugate function of $u_n$. Then $f_n=u_n+iv_n$ is holomorphic on the unit disk. Apply Montel's theorem to $\{f_n\}$.

(4). Let $f(z)=\sin(\pi z)$.